# Coded UI Test builder fails to recognize controls when XAP is hosted at different domain

Tags: silverlight, testing, cross-domain, coded-ui-tests

The Coded UI Test Builder fails to recognize Silverlight controls when the application (XAP) source is a different domain

I placed XAP at two different locations

1. http:\Domain1\MyApp\MyApp.XAP
2. http:\Domain2\MyApp\MyApp.XAP

My WebPage is at http:\Domain1\HomePage.html

If the Silverlight object's source is set to 1st one (same domain) it works fine and CUIT builder recognizes, records and playbacks properly. But, when I set the source to 2nd one (i.e. different domain), the CUIT builder fails to recognize Silverlight app.

The application itself work fine when hosted at Domain1 or Domain2. The recording is also successful when web page at DomainX refers to app at same DomainX. It fails to record when web page at DomainX refers to the same app at DomainY. What do I need to make it work?

Thanks

PS: Please note that the Silverlight application itself works fine no matter from which domain I am using - I have appropriate crossdomain policy file available and enableHtmlAccess set to true.
I have also verified presence of automation helper dll in XAP at both places (infact same XAP has been placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had logged this bug on MSDN connect - [Coded UI Test builder fails to recognize Silverlight controls in cross domain XAP](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688067/coded-ui-test-builder-fails-to-recognize-silverlight-controls-in-cross-domain-xap)
This has been marked as "**Won't Fix**":

"*We have investigated this scenario and determined that cross-domain XAPs cannot be supported by Coded UI Test. We use CreateFromXAML apis to enable the UI Testing component for Silverlight and
this API is failing for cross domain XAPs. Unfortunately, we have not been able to identify a workaround either. Closing the bug as Won't fix*"